# Pass info to db with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to pass the information from my HTML list to a database via Ajax jQuery. I'm unsure if my approach will work and how I should proceed. My biggest issue is how to get the correct information from the list so I can pass them to the PHP page and insert them. What I'm getting from my `get_data` function is something like this:

> James blue Looks Good
>
> Rebecka black Looks very bad

What I will be trying to do is insert this info to my database in the colors.php file. My table looks like this:

```
person
color_name
opinion
```

So it should for example look like this:

```
person = James
color_name = blue
opinion = Looks good
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <ul data-person="James">
    <li data-color_opinion="blue">Looks good</li>
    <li data-color_opinion="green">Looks ok</li>
  </ul>
  <ul data-person="Rebecka">
    <li data-color_opinion="blue">Looks bad</li>
    <li data-color_opinion="black">Looks very bad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JQuery Ajax**

```
function get_data() {
  $.each($('ul'), function(i, el) {
    $.each($(el).find("[data-color_opinion]"), function(j, child) {
      let person = $(el).data('person');
      let color_name = $(child).data('color_opinion');
      let opinion = $(child).text();
    });
  });
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'colors.php',
  data: get_data(),
  success: function(data) {
    //data is what your PHP page send you back,
    //what do you want to do with it?
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: @RacilHilan Thank you this is exactly what i was trying to accomplish. What would i have to try and do in my success: function(data) { } to pass these to my php file? I guess just setting them like i have now does not work?

Comment: `data: get_data()` is what you pass to your PHP file. `success: function(data)` is what you get back from it. I will update your question to show you the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration is overwriting the values of the `person`, `color_name`, and `opinion` variables. And the `get_data()` is not returning anything anyway, so nothing gets assigned to `data` and nothing gets posted to your PHP page.

You need to save the collected values in each iteration, probably in an array, and then return that array at the end. I don't know what your PHP page is expecting, but something like this:

```js
function get_data() {
  var data = [];
  $.each($('ul'), function(i, el) {
    $.each($(el).find("[data-color_opinion]"), function(j, child) {
      let person = $(el).data('person');
      let color_name = $(child).data('color_opinion');
      let opinion = $(child).text();
      data.push({ Person: person, ColorName: color_name, Opinion: opinion });
    });
  });
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your get_data function is not returning anything.

```
function get_data(){
  // initialize an empty js object/dict
  let data = {}
  $.each($('ul'), function(i, el){

        $.each($(el).find("[data-color_opinion]"), function(j, child){

          let person = $(el).data('person');
          let color_name = $(child).data('color_opinion');
          let opinion = $(child).text();
          // push to object
          data[person]["color_name"] = color_name;
          data[person]["opinion"] = opinion
          });

     });
     return data;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an array of objects that when sent to php would become an array of associative arrays that you can loop over

Currently in your `each` you aren't doing anything with each variable. Will use those to create an object.

Also your function doesn't have a `return` so will have it return the results array

```js
function get_data() {
  // empty array to populate
  let dataArray = [];

  $('ul[data-person]').each(function(i, el) {
    let $ul = $(this),
      $items = $ul.children('[data-color_opinion]'),
      // get data-person value from <ul>
      person = $ul.data('person');
    // now loop over the items
    $items.each(function(i, el) {
      let $item = $(el)
      let obj = {
        person: person, // from above
        color_name: $item.data('color_opinion'),
        opinion : $item.text()
      };      
      dataArray.push(obj);
    });
  });  
  return dataArray;

}


console.log(get_data())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul data-person="James">
    <li data-color_opinion="blue">Looks good</li>
    <li data-color_opinion="green">Looks ok</li>
  </ul>
  <ul data-person="Rebecka">
    <li data-color_opinion="blue">Looks bad</li>
    <li data-color_opinion="black">Looks very bad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```